# Read all files in a directory in perl

Tags: perl, file

in the first part of my code, I read a file and store different parts of it in different files in a directory and in the following I wanna read all the files in that directory that I build it in the first part of code:

```
while(<file>){

#making files in directory Dir

}

opendir(Dir, $indirname) or die "cannot open directory $indirname";
@docs = grep(/\.txt$/,readdir(Dir));
foreach $d (@Dir) {
    $rdir="$indirname/$d";
    open (res,$rdir) or die "could not open $rdir";
    while(<res>){


}
```

but with this code, the last line of the last file wont be read

Comment: What makes you think the last line of the last file won't be read?

Comment: dont use bareword filehandle, do like `open (my $res,'<',$rdir) or die "could not open $rdir $!";`

Comment: I think your foreach line should be `foreach $d (@docs) {`

Answer (score 16):

As I don't know what you are doing in the line reading loop and don't understand @docs and @Dir, I'll show code that 'works' for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;

my $dir = './_tmp/readFID';
foreach my $fp (glob("$dir/*.txt")) {
  printf "%s\n", $fp;
  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
  while (<$fh>) {
    printf "  %s", $_;
  }
  close $fh or die "can't read close '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
}
```

output:

```
./_tmp/readFID/123.txt
  1
  2
  3
./_tmp/readFID/45.txt
  4
  5
./_tmp/readFID/678.txt
  6
  7
  8
```

Perhaps you can spot a relevant difference to your script.

Answer (score 5):

I modified the code slightly to just test the basic idea in a directory containing my perl programs and it does seem to work. You should be iterating through @docs instead of @dir though (and I highly recommend using both the strict and warnings pragmas).

```
opendir(DIR, ".") or die "cannot open directory";
@docs = grep(/\.pl$/,readdir(DIR));
foreach $file (@docs) {
    open (RES, $file) or die "could not open $file\n";
    while(<RES>){
        print "$_";
    }
}
```

Comment: using a file path instead of `.` it will not read file and die with an error msg 'could not open $file'. It will work only for current directory.

Answer (score 1):

[`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) does what you want, without the open/close stuff. And once you stick a group of files into `@ARGV` the "diamond" operator works as normal.

```
@ARGV = <$indirname/*.txt>;
while ( <> ) { 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: beware the -i switch; it can make that seemingly convenient feature harmful